# Integrating NA (network analysis/routing) service in Web AppBuilder?

Tags: network-analyst, routing, arcgis-web-appbuilder

We had a requirement for routing in our application. As the arcgis online routing service is credit based we have published our own network routing service in arcgis server 10.6 using the road layer we had. It is working in ArcMap by using only the starting and ending point coordinates (not by start/end point location names).  how do we integrate it in our WAB based application as the "Directions" widget is  not supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this same issue. It seems that when you publish it in the ArcGIS Server you can enable the network analysis and copy the NAServer link. If you're working in ArcGIS Online, it will not accept these links. You will require to work directly in ArcGIS Portal and connect the network service from your Server.

In here https://github.com/Esri/network-analysis-services they explain how to configure your own ArcGIS Portal for customizing your network.

Bottom line, ArcGIS Online wont allow any modifications, you need to configure your own ArcGIS Portal for using these services (https://github.com/Esri/network-analysis-services/wiki/ConfiguringRoutingServicesWithPortalForArcGIS).